# Which key to export for PGP encryption and signing on different devices?

Tags: security, encryption, pgp, openpgp

I recently created a PGP keypair using GnuPG keychain tool on mac. I can see that it automatically creates a master key and an encryption sub key. Now I want to use a key for encryption and signing on my smartphone as well.

1. So what is the best practice for it?
2. Does one create new subkeys for smartphone for this purpose or use the same which were generated?
3. Can you please provide an example for same?

Comment: I have no problem with downvote of a question but please specify the reason as well so I know what is wrong in it. It is misusing of rights if you are downvoting without any reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an additional signing subkey (`gpg --edit-key [key-id]`, `addkey`) and then only export the subkeys. If the keys on your smartphone get compromised, you only need to exchange the subkeys, and do not have to distribute your key again.

You could create an additional signing subkey for each device. For encryption subkeys this is a little bit more complicated, as the OpenPGP protocol does not know a way to bind keys to certain usage or devices; the other party's client will usually just select the newest usable encryption subkey, so you'll have to use the same encryption subkey on all devices.

Comment: Thanks @Jens for your answer. So can I say that once we have made the initial subkeys (say multiple signing subkeys and one encryption subkey) then we will not require the master private key in day to day use? If so then can I remove the private key from my laptop and store in a safe flash drive and just keep the encryption subkey and signing subkey on my laptop? I am just afraid that I might lose my master private key if I keep it on my laptop. What do people normally do for it?

Comment: Yes, this is called an "offline primary key". When exporting subkeys only, GnuPG will create some "private primary key stub" for technical reasons, which does not include the actual private key.

Comment: Thanks for clarification Jens.